# Using Docker in Windows 10 - For HDP I executed 'sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh' but received a port 50079 error

Tags: docker, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using Docker (using latest version of Docker Desktop - also beginner with Docker) in Windows 10. I downloaded the latest HDP for Docker, unzip the folder and executed the script 'sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh' in Git Bash I received an error with port 50079 as shown in the screenshot below. I have no other containers, just this one. There are no active connections for port 50079.

[image]

Even though this port error outlined above, I can start the HDP container (as shown below), and I can access the shell (even run Apache Pig), but I cannot access port 8080 and 1080 etc via the Google Chrome browser (I checked Edge and Firefox but not worked as well). For instance, when I type 127.0.0.1:8080 it says connection refused. Additionally, I cannot start sandbox-proxy in Docker. Please can you help me resolve the port issues.

[image]

Comment: The port `50079` might be already in use. Perhaps you have another container publishing on that port. Check this out using `docker ps -a`. Remove the suspect containers and retry

Comment: I have no other containers, just this one, so there would be no conflict with another container. Do you know what else I can try to resolve the problem?

Comment: Usually last error in your logs suggests that the port is in use by a different process. Can you also run a `netstat -o` and see if you can spot something on that port? If not, the issue might be related to elevated privileges being required for that operation

Comment: Thank you, just ran this, but there is no active connections for port 50079. Is there anything else I can check for?

Comment: I've no other ideas and unfortunately I don't have a Windows machine to reproduce.

Comment: Execute `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` and check is your port (50079) in any of response range?

Comment: @MiladAghamohammadi I tried this, it comes up in port exclusion ranges. The start port for one is 50060 and end port is 50159, which 50079 would be part of. Is it possible make this port available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `docker error response from daemon ports are not available ... An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions` error, you should first execute `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` and check your desire port is in one of them range or not. If is in range, Docker for Windows and Hyper-V are responsible for all of those excluded port ranges above.

Base of [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-459205576) maybe below commands solve your problem. For steps 1 and 3, you need to run this as an administrator in PowerShell.

```
1-Disable hyper-v with this command(which will required a couple of restarts)
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

2-When you finish all the required restarts, reserve the port you want so hyper-v doesn't reserve it back
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50079 numberofports=1

3-Re-Enable hyper-V (which will require a couple of restart)
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

after all restarts run your command and probably your containers will be work.